# What configurations affect the speed of DDL statements in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, ddl, query-performance

I would like to setup PostgreSQL in such a way that dropping and recreating the entire database (~100 tables/views + a few rows per table) is as fast as possible.
This is for a development environment where data integrity is not important.
This database reset will happen very often.

What are the configuration options that might help with this (or psql meta commands that can help speed this process up)

EDIT:
Imagine i have a single sql file (that i constantly edit and save) that creates everything needed in an empty database.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE ...
INSERT INTO ...
CREATE TABLE ...
INSERT INTO ...
COMMIT;
```

I need it to run as fast as possible, right now it takes a few seconds even for about 10 tables, i would like it to be under 1 sec

Comment: The fastest way to re-create the database is to create it from a template `create database dev template dev_base`

Comment: thanks, i don't think it fits my need (probably asked the question wrong, i'll add an update)

Comment: Everyone would like their database to run faster. There isn't a magical option though. There is no `SET run_speed_slow = false;` that will make things magically speed up everywhere. You have to tell us *what* is slow. My answer gets you the *fastest* recreation time possible. What is not satisfactory about that? What do you want?

Comment: This is what i want :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407442/optimise-postgresql-for-fast-testing/ and it looks like there are magic settings :). I'll test the solutions in those threads and reply back here

Comment: These settings are probably the ones i am looking for https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/non-durability.html but i have not tested them yet. I'll get back with results

Comment: Most of that advice is bad advice, old advice or not applicable. First, COPY is transactional. Asychronous commits don't help it move faster because it's not serially committing every row. Most the despez article is old -- over a decade. There is no point in even benchmarking INSERT against COPY: COPY is substantially faster and always will be (per the article too). Setting fsync off is extremely dangerous. I would never suggest it. And wal_logging doesn't slow down copy, because [copy isn't wal logged](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html)

Comment: I am not referring to the article linked at the top, i am referring to the specific answers given by Craig Ringer, that was in 2012 and he knows what he is talking about, and as stated in this question, i don't care about the data so fsync/nondurability is exactly what i need. Actually the second article about needing to run tests fast is almost the same as what i need (without the rollback at the end)

Comment: I'm glad you found what you need. But, that's not the  question you asked. If you're recreating an entire database you don't need faster `INSERT` statements. You need `COPY`. I'm not sure what effect `fsync` has on `COPY`. That's a good question. But, my guess is that it's *minor* because `COPY` isn't WAL at the default setting. That is to say, I'm unconvinced any of this helps you recreate any faster. TIAS. My method below, *will* help you reset a development machine. And, it'll likely be under a second. Craig is on this site too. Maybe I'll format the question here.

Comment: @RuslanTalpa see Craig's answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160812/2639 *If wal_level = minimal and you're COPYing into a table you just truncated or created in the same transaction as the COPY there isn't much point using unlogged tables since we don't write much WAL in this case. If you're using a wal_level > minimal, unlogged tables can have a big benefit if you intend to leave them unlogged, but are pointless if you're just loading into them then making them logged. The point is: use unlogged tables if you don't need durability. – Craig Ringer*

Comment: You asked to "drop and recreate the **entire** database" - to recreate or reset an entire database to a given state,  `create database` using a template is as fast as it gest, as it only copies files and does not do any DML or DDL. You maintain a "blueprint" your test-data in a template and to recreate the entire database, just clone that template.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i can not use a template. The schema comes form a plain text sql file (executed with psql) which is constantly being edited. It's a process to aid in development of a database schema, save *.sql file .... have it live in the database. Sorry if i was not explicit enougth

Answer (score 1):

In what sense is database integrity not important? Even if you don't care about integrity, if the production database doesn't accept entries in table `baz` because of a foreign key constraint against table `bar`, do you want that constraint emulated in development? Or do you want to find out you forgot about it when you move to production? Personally, I would *not* sacrifice integrity in development.

## Official toolkit, `pg_dump`, `pg_restore`

I would personally use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`. They're configurable, user-friendly and very easy to use. That said, there are faster options but I have *never* had a need for them for my use cases. The official tools do not support binary dumps, but they also work between versions fairly well.  [`pg_restore -1` will wrap the whole thing in a transaction and disable WAL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/160807/2639).

## Raw Data with `TABLESPACE`

If you're willing to make raw backups you can get far greater speed. You can do this,

1. Create a a folder somewhere like `/data/dbs` chown it to be owned the user/group `postgres`

   ```
   mkdir -p /data/dbs;
   chown postgres:postgres /data/dbs;
   ```
2. Make this into a [`TABLESPACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtablespace.html)

   ```
   CREATE TABLESPACE dbspace LOCATION '/data/dbs';
   ```
3. Create a database there..

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE foobar WITH TABLESPACE = dbspace;
   ```

Now you can connect to `-d foobar`. And do some stuff.

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( idfoo serial PRIMARY KEY, name text );
CREATE TABLE baz ( idbaz serial, idfoo int REFERENCES foo );
INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('foo'), ('bar');
INSERT INTO baz (idfoo) SELECT idfoo FROM foo;
```

Now you can disconnect.. you can copy the data-directory to backup. this process can be scripted easily. For me,

- the data directory is `PG_9.5_201510051` for you it may different.
- the command to stop PostgreSQL runs though `/usr/sbin/service` (I use Ubuntu)

So for me, it looks like this.

```
sudo service postgresql stop
sudo cp -pR PG_9.5_201510051/ backup
sudo service postgresql start
```

Reconnect.

```
DROP TABLE foo CASCADE;
```

Then when disconnect and again stop the service we can restore the backup (also easily scripted),

```
service postgresql stop;
cp -pR backup/ PG_9.5_201510051/
```

Upon reconnecting, `foo` is magically back and restored. You can't get faster than this...

### Not fast enough?

If this isn't fast enough. In the event your database has TB of data or something crazy.

- You can use `rsync` to only synchronize files changed.
- You can likely use ZFS snapshots or [BTRFS snapshots](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-create-and-manage-btrfs-snapshots-and-rollbacks-linux-part-2) on a block device mounted to the data directory. YMMV.

Comment: Long and detailed answer (thank you) but that is not my question. Integrity is not important in the sense that i don't care if the data gets corrupted (because it was not flushed to the disk) when the power to my computer goes down. I am not interested in backing up my data at all. Imagine i have a single sql script/file that has everything (table definition and data), i need it to run as fast as possible when executed against an empty database

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear enough and made you waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i was looking for these settings https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/non-durability.html
These posts also helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407442/optimise-postgresql-for-fast-testing/

With settings turned off (what i need)

```
fsync = off
synchronous_commit = off
full_page_writes = off

$ time reset_db.sh 

real    0m0.725s
user    0m0.068s
sys 0m0.101s
```

With settings turned on (how it is by default)

```
fsync = on
synchronous_commit = on
full_page_writes = on

$ time reset_db.sh 

real    0m3.280s
user    0m0.069s
sys 0m0.102s
```

PS: thanks to everyone trying to help, sorry if the question was not clear enough.

Comment: I want to see the dump.

Comment: The dump (sql file with DDL statements) is not important, this (my script/method) needs to work for anyone trying to iteratively work on the schema of his database, just by editing DDL statements in a plain sql file. The time or course will vary for each schema but the important part is that for this particular test case there was a big speedup with those settings which i think will also work for other schemas

Comment: It's important because we can't verify what you're claiming.