# To what extent do the "non-durability features" affect COPY's performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, copy

[**COPY** is documented as *not* being WAL-logged if it's loaded on the same transactions..](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html)

> In minimal level, **WAL-logging of some bulk operations can be safely skipped**, which can make those operations much faster (see Section 14.4.7). Operations in which this optimization can be applied include: CREATE TABLE AS, 
>   CREATE INDEX, 
>   CLUSTER, 
>   **COPY into tables that were created or truncated in the same transaction**

With that said, **do any of the [non-durability features](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/non-durability.html) speed up a `pg_restore -1`?**

> **-1 --single-transaction** Execute the **restore as a single transaction (that is, wrap the emitted commands in BEGIN/COMMIT)**. This ensures that either all the commands complete successfully, or no changes are applied. This option implies --exit-on-error.

- `COPY` is a single transaction, will `synchronous_commit` do anything? Or does that only speed up batch-`INSERTS`?
- Does making the initial table `UNLOGGED` matter if `COPY` ignores the WAL log anyway?
- What about `max_wal_size` and `checkpoint_timeout`? I assume they would do nothing without WAL-logging?
- To what extent does turning off `fsync` do anything other than playing with fire? Are we likely to see a speed up by turning it off?

[*question inspired by @Craig Ringer's answer on SO*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12207237/124486)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you refer to is talking about bulkloading a DB, not restoring a dump.

---

`synchronous_commit` will have minimal to no effect on `COPY`, since there's only one commit at the end.

`COPY` can only *reduce* WAL, not ignore it, and only if `wal_level = minimal`. Most production systems run with `wal_level = hot_standby` (in pg10, `wal_level = replica`) or higher. `UNLOGGED` tables absolutely do benefit `COPY` at higher `wal_level`, but only if you do not later plan on making the table logged. If you do, you're just deferring the WAL cost, since it'll be paid when you convert the `UNLOGGED` table to `LOGGED` instead of at `COPY` time. Use `UNLOGGED` tables if you can regenerate and reload the data later in case of crash and you don't need it to replicate. `pg_restore` will restore unlogged tables as unlogged, and logged tables as logged, so it's kind of a moot point.

Don't turn `fsync` off unless you *really* know what you're doing, or you don't care about your data. For bulk loading a new blank PostgreSQL instance, `wal_level = minimal` and `synchronous_commit = off` are probably going to be just as good. Better, even, since you avoid a whole bunch of WAL writing.

`max_wal_size` won't make much difference with bulk loading if `wal_level = minimal`. If you're using a higher WAL level you do need to tune checkpoints for best results. `checkpoint_timeout` doesn't really matter since it generally only comes into play on idle-ish systems.

So if you're using `pg_restore` to a system configured for physical replication (hot standby/warm standby/archive PITR) you've got to pay the costs for that, and there's not much you can do to speed things up on top of what `COPY` already does. `pg_restore` uses `COPY`.

Comment: So is it fair to say the only advice to make COPY on `wal_level=minimal` faster is to use UNLOGGED tables to turn wal off, and keep them unlogged? Shy of that, there isn't much you can do?

Comment: Also, is the reduction in WAL under `COPY` explained/documented  anywhere?

Comment: Yes, you quoted the relevant documentation in your question.

Comment: If `wal_level = minimal` and you're `COPY`ing into a table you just truncated or created in the same transaction as the `COPY` there isn't much point using unlogged tables since we don't write much WAL in this case. If you're using a `wal_level` > `minimal`, unlogged tables can have a big benefit if you intend to leave them unlogged, but are pointless if you're just loading into them then making them logged. The point is: use unlogged tables if you don't need durability.

Comment: Excellent, so under wal_level = minimal, there simply isn't much the non-durable options can do for you? That was my assumption when I wrote this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160771/2639

Comment: *under wal_level = minimal, there simply isn't much the non-durable options can do* **for `COPY`, `pg_restore`, etc**. If you're doing lots of small xacts or even individual `insert`s batched into xacts, etc, it changes.